# Check in Visual Studio if an index parameter can be used with a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, indexer

Let's say I have a following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
```

Now let's say I use this class elsewhere in the code and need to check if an indexer parameter can be used with the class. I have to write the starting bracket and only then Visual Studio displays the Quick Info:

```
var test = new Test();
test[ // Visual Studio now displays "int Test[int index]"
```

For my own code this isn't a problem but what about when using classes provided by others? Do I have to write the starting bracket to check if an index parameter is accepted:

1. Quick Info shown -> class can be used with index parameters
2. Quick Info not shown -> class cannot be used with index parameters

The places I thought it could show up in (but didn't): variable/class symbol for `test` in Quick Info, Class View, Method list in intellisense view.

Comment: Well, yes, but I was curious to see if there were options that would enable me to skip the documentation and stick to Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the Object Browser if the type exposes a `this[T]` member:

[image: Visual Studio Object Browser]